# Is it possible to create a file backed Canvas in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I would like to create a `Canvas` instance that is too big to be backed by a heap memory `Bitmap`, lets say 5000x5000 pixels (approx. 95MB). I would like this very large `Canvas` to send all the various draw operations directly to a bitmap file. Unfortunately the `Bitmap` class in Android is marked `final` so I can't provide my own implementation. Does anyone have an idea if and how this might be accomplished? I'm not very interested in performance, 10 seconds to write make a few dozen draw operations is fine, the goal is to not get out of memory errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no facility to provide the function you are asking, and even if there were, to do such operations to a file would provide horrendous performance.

Probably the only reasonable way is to only store the drawing operations, and create a `Canvas` that is the same size as the device screen that would serve as a "window" into the while 5000x5000 pixel canvas. For detailed explanation see my answer to a related question here: [Android - is there a possibility to make infinite canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018248/android-is-there-a-possibility-to-make-infinite-canvas/18063263#18063263)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea I had that I think could theoretically work, but would probably require far too much effort:

Create a subclass of `Canvas` that contains many smaller `Canvas` objects inside it. These would represent tiles of the overall `Canvas`. These tiles should be small enough to fit in memory at least one at a time. Create one file for each inner tile `Canvas` and use it to store uncompressed pixel data from a `Buffer`.

When a draw operation occurs on the overall `Canvas` figure out which tiles need to be drawn to. One at a time read the file for that tile into a `Bitmap` in memory and perform the possibly clipped draw and then save the `Bitmap` data back to the file and close it.

Theoretically it sounds possible, realistically it sounds like too much work.